# Building Mono.Options under .NET Core CLI (dotnet build)

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to use [`Mono.Options`](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Mono.Options/Mono.Options/Options.cs) under [.NET Core](http://dotnet.github.io/),¹ using its command-line tools.

I initially tried loading it [from NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.Options) using a dependency declaration in my `project.json` file, but `dotnet restore` complains that the package is not compatible with the `dnxcore50` framework.²

I therefore decided to try building it from source. I noticed in the `Mono.Options` source code that it has a [`PCL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg597391.aspx) build option. Thinking that maybe PCL was a close-enough approximation to .NET Core, I tried creating a DLL project to build it with that setting enabled:

```js
{
    "version": "0.0.0-d95ccb2ca5",
    "compilationOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": false,
        "define": [ "PCL" ],
    },

    "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.0.0-rc2-23811"
    },

    "compile": [ "*.cs" ],

    "frameworks": {
        "dnxcore50": { }
    }
}
```

I then placed a copy of `Options.cs` downloaded from the link above in the same directory and said `dotnet build`, which gives these errors:

```
.../Mono/Options.cs(137,22): error CS0234: The
type or namespace name 'Serialization' does not exist in the namespace
'System.Runtime' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
.../Mono/Options.cs(729,27): error CS0246: The
type or namespace name 'KeyedCollection<,>' could not be found (are you
missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

...plus several others all stemming from those two key errors.

That finally brings me to my questions:

1. Why is `System.Runtime.Serialization` missing? According to [the docs](http://dotnet.github.io/api/System.Runtime.Serialization.html), it is supposed to be part of .NET Core.
2. I later added explicit dependencies for the parent packages of the two namespaces the compiler is complaining about:

   ```js
   ...
   "frameworks": {
       "dotnet5.4": {
           "dependencies": {
               "System.ObjectModel": "4.0.*",
               "System.Runtime": "4.1.0-rc2-23811"
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   `dotnet restore` then succeeds, and most of the build errors go away, but the first error about `Serialization` continues to occur. Is .NET Core simply incomplete at this time?
3. Is there a workaround other than just waiting for this class to be ported over?
4. I used `dnxcore50` in the initial project file because that's how `dotnet new` generated it. The change to `dotnet5.4` seems to be necessary according to [the ASP.NET 5 package search engine](http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/), but is that change kosher with .NET Core?³

---

**Asides**

1. Why? Because it's 2016 and .NET *still* doesn't have command-line option parsing built-in. Grrrr. Maybe Microsoft's acquisition of Xamarin will result in `Mono.Options` being included in .NET Core. Meanwhile...
2. `Mono.Options` 4.2.2.1 — released after this question was asked — solves this compatibility problem.
3. The ASP.NET 5 package search results imply that `netcore50` should also work for my purposes, but then I get complaints about `no run-time assembly compatible with osx.10.10-x64`.

   This is happening on an OS X 10.10 machine with Mono 4.2.1 installed. `Mono.Options` *does* build under that, obviously. This question came up because I'm trying to switch some of my simpler existing projects to this new, lighter runtime.

Comment: Microsoft now provides  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils/ . An useful document is here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt763239.aspx

Comment: @Smartkid: Thank you! Only 11 years late, but finally here. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `System.Runtime.Serialization` mechanism was [purposefully removed from .NET Core](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/02/10/porting-to-net-core/). (Scroll down to the "Binary serialization" section.) Fortunately, `Mono.Options` doesn't actually use that interface when you build it in PCL mode, so the fix is simple: move the `using System.Runtime.Serialization` line down a few lines into the `#else` clause so it isn't seen when `PCL` is defined.

Avoid RC2 if possible. It is still in development, and I see several issues open on GitHub.

Once on RC1, you can use http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net to find the missing packages and their versions against RC1.

It would be better to build against a certain .NET Platform Standard, instead of a single profile, such as 5.4 in RC1 (1.3 in RC2).

As for your side questions,

- There are already many open source command line parsing libraries, so Microsoft does not attempt to force you to use one.
- .NET Core has a different design from .NET Framework and Mono. Thus, the migration pains stand but can be easily remedied when Microsoft has all tool chain in place. Wait and wait.

Comment: Re the package search: That's an useful tool; thanks! Following its hints, I updated the project file per the edited question, but the `Serialization` problem remains. Suggestions?

Comment: Re command line parsing libraries: I'm not asking Microsoft to "force" me to use theirs. I simply believe that we'd have a lot fewer reinvented wheels if Microsoft shipped a canonical implementation; there would certainly be less time spent chasing down NuGet packages and dealing with the generally lower quality of non-MSDN docs. The existence of [`getopt(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt) on POSIX platforms keeps the number of command line parsing libraries on those platforms low. "Good enough and preinstalled" beats third-party every time.

Comment: Re RC2: Lots of software I use to good effect has open Github issues. If you know of a specific issue that's on-topic for this question, please point to it. Until then, I'm going to believe that Microsoft is using "RC" the same way the rest of the software world does, meaning "release candidate," implying "feature-complete but possibly buggy", with RC2 less buggy than RC1.

Comment: @WarrenYoung the MSDN blog post explains the serialization part.

Comment: Indeed it does! I've edited your answer with the explicit solution to the problem. (And I'll be bugging the `Mono.Options` maintainers about the bug in their code. :) )

Answer (score 1):

Have you updated to the latest version: 4.2.2? This is now a PCL assembly that should support all .NET platforms, including .NETCore4.5.

In addition to supporting more platforms, this version allows for basic type conversion of arguments. The only restriction is that the `TypeDesciptor` operations are not supported, but all `IConvertable` operations are.

This was all done in this PR: https://github.com/mono/mono/pull/2662

Comment: The problem turned out to be the `using System.Runtime.Serialization` statement on line 137 of `Options.cs`. In PCL mode, `Options.cs` doesn't actually use that namespace (see ifdef'd-out `Serializable` stuff below that) so if If you move that down about 4 lines into the `#else` block, `Options.cs` builds under .NET Core directly, (This as opposed to being *referencable* from a .NET Core project via NuGet.) I've sent an email to the project maintainers via nuget.org's feedback mechanism.

Comment: I am one of the maintainers. I will update the source. Thanks for letting us know. Does the assembly work when referenced? PRs against mono take some time :)

Comment: Re referencing: Sorry, no. Adding `"Mono.Options": "4.2.2"` to the `project.json` file's `dependencies` section fails if `frameworks` is set to `dnxcore50`, the default value, apparently because there is not an explicit .NET Core build of the project. If you then change it to `netcore45` or `dotnet5.4`, it yells a lot about no available packages for `osx.10.10-x64`, plus some stuff about incompatibilities with the F# core DLLs. (Try `dotnet new --lang f#`, then modify the `project.json` as specified.)

Comment: I am making some changes to the project settings and portable profiles... Hopefully that will be all that is needed and I can update the NuGet with .NETCore support very soon

Comment: Just updated Mono.Options to v4.2.2.1: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.Options/4.2.2.1
That should fix it.

Comment: I tried with a F# console app and everything should be there :) You may have to manually add the `"System.ObjectModel" : "4.0.0.0"` dependency...

Comment: Verified! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The docs are not technically wrong. The `System.Runtime.Serialization` namespace does still exist in .NET Core 1.0 RC2, but the top level of the namespace is now almost empty because of [the removal of binary serialization](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/02/10/porting-to-net-core/). That's why the `using System.Runtime.Serialization` line fails, even with an explicit dependency on `System.Runtime`.

All of the types on the linked documentation page are implemented in the `Primitives` sub-namespace in .NET Core. Adding the following to your `project.json` file will therefore also allow the `using` statement to succeed:

```
"System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives": "4.1.0-beta-23516"
```